# plusOut code java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that will give this output:

```
plusOut("12xy34", "xy") → "++xy++"
```

it returns a string where the characters in the original have been replaced by + except for where the 2nd string appears in the first string, but im having problems with my code. Here it is:

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
  String newString = "";
  for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++) {
    if (str.substring(i, word.length()).equals(word)) {
      newString = newString + str.substring(i, word.length());
    }
    else {
      newString = newString + "+";
    }
  }
  return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code, see the comments.

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
    String newString = "";
    // iterate up to length() to catch the last char if word.length() is 1
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        // use min() to avoid an IndexOutOfRange
        String sub = str.substring(i, Math.min(i+word.length(), str.length()));
        if (sub.equals(word)) {
            newString = newString + sub;
            // skip remaining characters of word
            i += sub.length()-1;
        }
        else {
            newString = newString + "+";
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

In addition to that, I'd use a `StringBuilder` instead of the `+` operator.

Comment: You could do it without substring (see my answer below). But tested and works, +1 for correcting original code instead of writing from scratch.

Comment: It's generally a very bad idea to concatenate strings within loops, try a `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should really tell us what specific problems you are facing with your current code. In any case, here's how I would do it:

- Split `str` on all occurrences of `word` to form a `String[]`.
- Loop through this array and append a number of `'+'` characters to `newString` corresponding to the length of whatever element of the array you're on.
- On the same loop iteration, append `word` to `newString`, unless of course you're on the last element of the array.

This is what I mean:

```
public static String plusOut(String str, String word) {
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    String[] split = str.split(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < split[i].length(); j++)
            newString.append('+');

        if (i != split.length - 1)
            newString.append(word);
    }

    return newString.toString();
}
```

Oh and just another tip: try to avoid appending to strings repeatedly within a loop. If you need to, use a `StringBuilder` instead.

---

```
System.out.println(plusOut("12xy34", "xy"));
```

```
++xy++
```

Comment: The regex one-liner would everything except `x` or `y` with `+` regardless where the `x` or `y` would occur.  So `plusOne("yyyy")` would return `"yyyy"`, which I don't think the intention is...

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way I can think of is to use regular expressions and do a replaceAll.

General idea will be to get the second character build an regex with that and replaceAll with the regular expression and the replacement character.

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {

String regEx="[^"+Pattern.quote(word)+"]";

str.replaceAll(regEx,"+");

}
```

Note that the Pattern.quote() will make sure that your word won't screw the regex.

I didn't try out the code, but it should work without a problem.

Comment: However, it falls over when trying something like `plusOne("xxxyxx12yx12")` returning `xxxyxx++yx++` (with 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

This will do that for you.

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {

    if(!str.contains(word)){
        System.out.println("Word not found in string!");
        return "Ut-oh!";
    }
    int indexOfStart = str.indexOf(word);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<indexOfStart; i++){
        sb.append('+');
    }

    sb.append(word);

    for(int i=indexOfStart+word.length(); i < str.length(); i++){
        sb.append('+');
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static String plusOut(String word, String find) {
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
    int start = word.indexOf(find);
    if (start > -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
            newStr.append("+");
        }
        newStr.append(find);
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - (start + find.length()); i++) {
            newStr.append("+");
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Comment: Best to use a string builder if you are doing that, but looks like a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

So many answers! Well, here's mine as well:

```
public static String plusOut(String str, String word) {
    String output = "";
    int index = str.indexOf(word); // if -1 is returned, replace all chars
    for (int i= 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(i == index)
        {
            output += word;
            i += word.length() -1; // because i++ will still occurr
            continue;
        }
        output += "+";
    }
    return output;
}
```

and test code in main:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "somethinghello12345.1!#";
    System.out.println(test + " -> " + plusOut(test, "hello"));

    test = "somethinghello12345.1!#";
    System.out.println(test + " -> " + plusOut(test, "not gonna work"));
}
```

will produce the ouput:

```
somethinghello12345.1!# -> +++++++++hello+++++++++
somethinghello12345.1!# -> +++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Note that for larger Strings, `StringBuilder` is recommended. I'm only using the concatenation operator for simplicity's sake here.